# Uploading app which doesn't support iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios

I have submitted a binary to iTunes connect, and now the status of the app is "missing screenshot". When I scroll over it, it tells me that I am missing localized screenshots for English.

Previously, I have uploaded 4 screenshots for iPhone and iPod touch. At one point it gave me an error that I needed to upload 5th gen screenshots because my app supported these.

The problem is that my app does **not** support the iphone 5 screen size.

How can I make iTunes connect consider my app as only a 4th gen app?

Comment: Just upload your old iPhone screenshots there.

Comment: But when they test the app, won't it get rejected? With the largest screen size, the layout is messed up, and they don't know that I can't support the largest layout.

Comment: The layout changes only when you add a launch image for your app in Xcode. If you haven't done this, it will not resize.

Comment: @Rofler just try by modifying ur iPhone4 screenshot image to 640 x 1136 (Resize same image) and put it as iPhone5 screenshot.